# dev_appserver on cloud shell still runs after termination

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-shell, dev-appserver

I'm running a dev server using dev_appserver.py on google app engine via cloud shell.

I'm doing so just like the tutorial for a first app says.
But with my own Flask app that delivers static files (index.html + some js and css).

It runs fine, but after I terminate it using *ctrl+c*, I can still access it using Web Preview.

The problem is, when I want to launch the same app with some changes, It does not change what Web Preview shows.

Things I tried:

- I looked for open processes using `ps`. Restarted the shell using **Restart**.
- Made sure the files are actually changed using the shell.
- Cleared cached data on local browser. Used different browser.
- Used --port option to launch the app with a different port. It worked fine but now I have 2 servers running.
- If I change the code before I terminate the dev_appserver script in the first place, it detects the changes and they are committed. After I terminate it it does not change even if I call dev_appserver again.

It may be that I don't actually understand what dev_appserver does? Maybe the Flask code itself still runs somehow? But how can I access it?

app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: server.app

libraries:
- name: flask
  version: 0.12
```

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, this has nothing to do with dev_appserver.py
The problem somehow is still cache.

I went to the site through my phone and saw that the request was actually sent.
So I added `app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0` to my Flask app,
started the server on a new port, and it now works as it should.